# How to use FirebaseFirestore as datasource for sfCalendar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sfcalendar

I have an app, a booking app, where a group of student will book their mentors for lectures. Bookings will be saved on my firestore database, with the collection "event". I want to know how to use those data to be as a source of my sfCalendar:

Here is my code of the sfcalendar

```
SfCalendar(
        view: CalendarView.month,
        dataSource: EventDataSource(_getDataSource()),
        // monthViewSettings: const MonthViewSettings(showAgenda: true),
        monthViewSettings: const MonthViewSettings(
            appointmentDisplayMode: MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment,
            showAgenda: true),
      )
```

here is my code of the EventDatasource

```
    class EventDataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  EventDataSource(List<Meeting> source) {
    appointments = source;
  }

  @override
  DateTime getStartTime(int index) {
    return appointments![index].from;
  }

  @override
  DateTime getEndTime(int index) {
    return appointments![index].to;
  }

  @override
  String getSubject(int index) {
    return appointments![index].eventName;
  }

  @override
  Color getColor(int index) {
    return appointments![index].background;
  }

  @override
  bool isAllDay(int index) {
    return appointments![index].isAllDay;
  }
}
```

This is the meeting class

```
 class Meeting {
  Meeting(this.eventName, this.from, this.to, this.background, this.isAllDay);

  String eventName;
  DateTime from;
  DateTime to;
  Color background;
  bool isAllDay;
}
```

this is the partial _getDataSource() code

```
List<Meeting> _getDataSource() {
    final List<Meeting> meetings = <Meeting>[];
    final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    final DateTime startTime =
        DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day, 9, 0, 0);
    final DateTime endTime = startTime.add(const Duration(hours: 2));
    meetings.add(Meeting(
        'Pitching', startTime, endTime, const Color(0xFF0F8644), false));
    meetings.add(Meeting('Meeting', startTime, endTime,
        const Color.fromARGB(255, 13, 58, 156), false));
    return meetings;
  }
```

I want to know how to get the data from database through a query, and assigning it inside the `Meeting()` class. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the firebase docs how to retrieve data from [firestore in flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart)

Basic example:

```
Future<List<Meeting>> _getDataSource() async {
    // db should be intialized instance of firestore
    final snapshot = await db.collection("event").withConverter(fromFirestore: Meeting.fromFirestore, toFirestore: Meeting.toFirestore).get();
    return snapshot.docs;
  }
```